# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required when starting tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, autowired

Coming up with an issue in regards to spring and tomcat. I have the following code

BookDAOImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class BookDAOImpl extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport implements BookDAO {

    private class BookMapper implements RowMapper<Book> {

        @Override
        public Book mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Book book = new Book();
            book.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            book.setTitle(resultSet.getString("title"));
            book.setAuthor(resultSet.getString("author"));
            book.setPublisher(resultSet.getString("publisher"));
            book.setPublicationDate(resultSet.getDate("publication_date"));
            book.setIsbn(resultSet.getString("isbn"));
            book.setAvailable(resultSet.getBoolean("available"));
            return book;
        }

    }
}
```

LibraryDataSource.java

```
@Component("dataSource")
public class LibraryDataSource extends DriverManagerDataSource {

    @Autowired
    public LibraryDataSource(@Value("${url}")String url, @Value("${user}")String username, @Value("${password}")String password) {
        super(url, username, password);
    }
}
```

application-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd" 
    default-autowire="byName">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.LibraryManagement.*" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:prop.properties"/>
</beans>
```

Now as far as i know the autowiring should pick up the dataSource and autowire it to the Repository but when i start tomcat i get the following error

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookDAOImpl' defined in file [P:\SourceControl\EclipseWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\WebLibraryManagemenet\WEB-INF\classes\com\LibraryManagement\access\impl\BookDAOImpl.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
```

Any idea whats going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following constructor to `BookDAOImpl`:

```
@Autowired 
public BookDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
    setDataSource(dataSource);
}
```

Comment: It works with Spring Boot `2.2.6.RELEASE`. However, could you add few words why what exactly going on? And how does this helps to solve the issue.